# Xcode keeps on crashing when indexing process starts

Tags: xcode, macos-sierra, xcode9-beta, xcode9beta6

I'm on my latest beta on both Xcode and

Mac - macOS High Sierra 10.13 beta 7

XCode - XCode 9 beta 6

Since yesterday after updating Xcode crashes when opening my project and when indexing starts. Other answers in stack overflow do not fix the issue.

Have attached full log [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rajesht1989/PublicAssets/master/Logs/Xcode%20crash%20log.txt)

Part of Crash log as follows

```
Process:               Xcode [665]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            Xcode
Version:               9.0 (13238.4)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [665]
User ID:               1105600005

Date/Time:             2017-08-24 07:59:26.512 +0530
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.13 (17A352a)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     3.0 (14Y661)
Anonymous UUID:        B0A9A8FC-BC57-8953-BB69-E279B3226BBF


Time Awake Since Boot: 630 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        19

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Illegal instruction: 4
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x4
Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 9M214v
mcount overflow

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff796ece76 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff796ec390 mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff52083445 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 341
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff52082797 __CFRunLoopRun + 1783
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff52081e13 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 483
5   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff513a1876 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 286
6   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff513a15e6 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 613
7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff513a1364 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 64
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff4f69f783 _DPSNextEvent + 2085
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff4fe34688 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 3044
10  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x000000010b45c8be -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 390
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff4f694591 -[NSApplication run] + 764
12  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff4f663736 NSApplicationMain + 804
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff795a6145 start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff796ece76 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff796ec390 mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff52083445 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 341
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff52082797 __CFRunLoopRun + 1783
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff52081e13 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 483
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff540ec3f6 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 277
6   com.apple.DTDeviceKitBase       0x000000011d2e94f8 +[DTDKRemoteDeviceConnection startServiceBrowsers] + 217
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff540fa6d8 __NSThread__start__ + 1197
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff798306c1 _pthread_body + 340
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7983056d _pthread_start + 377
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7982fc5d thread_start + 13

    0x7fff7983f000 -     0x7fff79846ff7  libsystem_symptoms.dylib (820.1.4) <24FD262C-9701-388A-AEDC-D675747F8CBD> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib
    0x7fff79847000 -     0x7fff7985aff7  libsystem_trace.dylib (829.1.2) <10955EBB-1AC8-3085-9A2D-F3088CA2DF71> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
    0x7fff7985c000 -     0x7fff79861ff7  libunwind.dylib (35.3) <6D4FCD49-D2A9-3233-95C7-A7635CE265F2> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
    0x7fff79862000 -     0x7fff7988dff7  libxpc.dylib (1205.1.10) <E7C5DB12-6D0E-3D1E-A743-F750DF112F5F> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 4
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 7883
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=871.0M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=871.0M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=1.6G written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=1.6G(100%)

                                  VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                          SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                       =======  ======= 
Accelerate framework                 384K        3 
Activity Tracing                     256K        2 
CG backing stores                   79.9M        5 
CG image                            1432K       57 
CG raster data                       104K        5 
CoreAnimation                       53.0M      357 
CoreGraphics                           8K        2 
CoreImage                            244K       28 
CoreServices                        3540K        2 
CoreUI image data                   4892K       30 
CoreUI image file                    308K       11 
Dispatch continuations              16.0M        2 
Foundation                           348K        5 
Image IO                            1956K       45 
JS JIT generated code                  8K        3 
JS JIT generated code (reserved)     1.0G        2         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
Kernel Alloc Once                      8K        2 
MALLOC                             444.7M      110 
MALLOC guard page                    192K       44 
MALLOC_LARGE (reserved)             7684K        3         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
Memory Tag 242                        12K        2 
Memory Tag 244                       128K        3 
Memory Tag 251                        60K        3 
Memory Tag 255                        32K        2 
SQLite page cache                   4928K       11 
STACK GUARD                         56.1M       28 
Stack                               21.2M       28 
VM_ALLOCATE                          116K       17 
WebKit Malloc                       1056K        3 
__DATA                              79.7M      619 
__FONT_DATA                            4K        2 
__GLSLBUILTINS                      2588K        2 
__LINKEDIT                         264.7M      200 
__TEXT                             606.4M      594 
__UNICODE                            556K        2 
libnetwork                           128K        2 
mapped file                        228.4M      231 
shared memory                        704K       21 
===========                       =======  ======= 
TOTAL                                2.8G     2450 
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space       1.8G     2450
```

Comment: What do you want us to do about it? That is not a programming question. Send a bug report to Apple.

Comment: @matt Have posted a bug and discussion but so far no reply from them. Ofcourse thia is not a programing question and i haven't tag any programming tag

Comment: @Rajesh I filed rdar://problem/34089659, which was marked as a duplicate of the closed rdar://problem/33983504. Hopefully we'll see a fix for this in the next release.

Comment: @Rajesh I'm not seeing this issue in beta 8. Looks like it's been fixed.

Comment: @SaagarJha yeah issue is fixed

Answer (score 0):

I would review recent changes to your .xcodeproj on the disk vs those in your repo. Xcode has crashed for me when I accidentally added a character to the xcproj file.

Comment: It wad fine until the latest mac beta is installed

Comment: Does it crash if you turn off spotlight indexing?

Comment: Have disabled spotlight indexing using `sudo mdutil -a -i off` but still crashes.

Answer (score -1):

Use the Terminal to go back in Git history to a previous commit until you find one where indexing works.
Let it finish indexing and then go back to head.

Comment: Have tried going back to previous commits but its of no use.